# store a large list of static strings (Swift)

Tags: xml, binary, swift, ios8

I am making an app for iOS 8 with Swift. I need to store long lists of strings. These will need to be read at any time during the app. What is the easiest way to accomplish this? XML files, plain text files, binary files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual from Objective-C experiences applies. You can really use any of the methods you mention. Some comments:

- XML: seems overkill. You would need a parser, etc.
- Exception: Apple's property lists (which is also an XML format). You can read the entire list with a one-liner
- Plain text: involves a few lines of code to read it, so it could be viable. It would be particularly easy to make the list in the first place (e.g. with excel or a text editor).
- Binary: not recommended for strings.
- Core Data: keeps the strings in a neat SQLite database, but is likely to be overkill as well.

e.g. for plist:

```
let wordList = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
```

Comment: To refine the answer: a property list is good if you read or write the entire list at once, infrequently. If the list is so large that keeping it in memory is unwise, and you find yourself doing things like reading the whole thing in, changing one line, then writing the whole thing out, Core Data might not be overkill.

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention that I'm launching the list with the app. It probably won't be changing at all after the app is installed. So I'll probably use a plist since I can edit that easily with XCode.

Comment: Good point, @rickster, which is why I mentioned it. Quemeful, If you have a few hundred words, plist is fine. If it is a few 1000 Core Data is probably worth it.